# Laravel: Check if Models have same relation

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have models: `Partido` and `Coalicion` related in a `many to many` relationship.
I need to know when two or more `Coalicion` has the same `Partido` related.

Hope I have explained myself.

Edit 1: 
Model:

```
class Coalicion extends Model
{
    public function partidos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Partido::class);
    }
}
```

Let's say users selected some elements from a select input and I grabbed them in an array and send them to the controller.

```
    ...
    public function example(Request $request)
        {
            $coaliciones = $request->coaliciones;
            foreach ($coaliciones as $c) {
                $coalicion = Coalicion::find($c);
                # Here we have a list of Coalicion model in a loop
                # Let's say the first iteration I can see the relationship
                dump($c->partidos);
            }
        }
```

This for example give me the following answer at the browser:

```
Collection {#1 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Partido {#271 ▶} #This is Partido with id 1
    1 => Partido {#268 ▶}
  ]
}
Collection {#2 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Partido {#279 ▶}
    1 => Partido {#280 ▶}
    2 => Partido {#283 ▶} #This is Partido with id 1
  ]
}
```

I need to know when the item 0 of the first Collection and the item 2 of the second Collection are the same.

Comment: send a example...and paste your model code here...

Comment: Done, is a Laravel/Eloquent specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda found a way but I don't know if it's the correct or best approach.
In Coalicion model I add the following `function`:

```
public function partidosId()
    {
        return $this->partidos->pluck('id');
    }
```

With this I can get only the `id`'s from the relations, then in the `controller` I created an empty `array()` and fill it with all my `id`s with a `foreach` loop, then, finishing up I evaluated if the `id`'s in the now filled `array` are unique, if the unique values are less than the length of the array then some models have the same relation (I don't know which but It's a start), e.g.:

```
public function example(Request $request)
    {
        $coaliciones = $request->coaliciones;
        $allItems = [];
        foreach ($coaliciones as $c) {
            $coalicion = Coalicion::find($c);
            $allItems = array_merge($allItems, $coalicion->partidosId()->toArray());
        }
        if (count(array_unique($allItems))<count($allItems)) {
            dd("Duplicates");
        }else{
            dd("Uniques");
        }
    }
```

If anyone find a better way or a way to know which are the ones with the duplicate relation please let me know